# cannot install nodejs. curl (23) failire writing output to destitanion

Tags: node.js

i Have a problem with installing nvm. When i type nvm install node im geeting this error
Any one solved same problem ?

```
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.1/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/gala/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64/node-v12.22.1-linux
Warning: -x64.tar.xz: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.1/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/gala/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.1/node-v12.22.1.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/gala/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.22.1/node-v12.22.1.tar.xz: 
Warning: Permission denied
                                                                            0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.1/node-v12.22.1.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/gala/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.22.1/node-v12.22.1.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you ran node or nvm as sudo? Check the permissions on `/home/gala/.nvm` and the other subdirectories shown in the path of the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same error, then I tried to download node archive manually and place it where nvm wants it, and then it works for me (as a temporary solution).

1. Download https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.1/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
2. Move it to `~/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64/node-v12.22.1-linux-x64.tar.xz`
3. Run `nvm install node` again